# TWOV at Sydney Airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, sydney, twov

I'm flying from the UK next week (British Citizen). Can someone just share their experience of the TWOV process at Sydney Airport T1?

I'm flying into Sydney from London via Abu Dhabi landing at 6am, and then onto Queenstown, New Zealand on Virgin Australia a couple hours later. Its all booked on one ticket and bags are checked through to NZ.

I just want to know what happens as you land and making sure I don't need to go through customs/immigration.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jack and welcome to travel exchange!
Are you afraid you need a visa for the Sydney Airport?

Comment: If you are a British citizen, consider applying for a [eVisitor visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/evisitor-651). It's free, in most instances approved instantly, and you don't need to worry about TWOV arrangements.

Comment: This https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/airport-guide/arriving/international and this https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/info-sheet/get-to-your-next-flight might help

Comment: Hi Joren - yes was just concerned if I got there and needed to clear customs/immigration. I believe I get the 8 hours and bags are checked through - so do I just go to international transit screening?

Comment: Hi @molypot - is there any difference applying for this instead of a transit visa?

Comment: Transit visas take days to process whereas eVisitor visas are generally approved instantly. Also the application for a eVisitor visa is much simpler than for a transit visa.

Answer (score 2):

From [Advance Passenger Processing - Australian Border Force](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/crossing-the-border/passenger-movement/advance-passenger-processing):

> **Processing transit passengers without a visa**
>
> In order to be eligible for transiting Australia without a visa, the person must:
>
> - be a traveller eligible to transit without a visa (TWOV)
> - enter Australia by aircraft
> - hold a confirmed onward booking to leave Australia within 8 hours of the person's arrival in Australia
> - hold documentation necessary to enter the country of their destination
> - remain in the transit lounge (if they want to clear immigration for any reason, they must obtain a visa in advance of travel)

Therefore, you will not require a Visa. Your bags will be automatically transferred to the other flight. There is no need to clear customs. Follow the signs to the Transit area where you will go through a security check to access the airside Departure area of the airport.

Comment: It's important to note for future readers that while this is valid in Sydney airport for a daytime connection if the passenger is from a qualifying country, this is not always valid in other circumstances. The first bullet point in the list links to https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/travellers-eligible-to-transit-without-visa which lists the eligible countries and also links to https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/transit-771/transit-facilities-at-australian-airports which gives the details for each airport.